# Valores não são convertidos em np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho a função:

```
def zero_to_null(x):
    if x == 0:
        x = np.nan
    return x
```

Uso series.apply:

```
Series.apply(zero_to_null)
```

Porém os valores 0 não são convertidos em np.nan:

```
Series.value_counts()

0        35
2         4
1         3
13        2
151       2
4         2
...
```

Alguém sabe o que se passa?

Answer (score 0):

A chamada `Series.apply`  do Pandas, como a maior parte das chamadas, não altera o valor "inplace" - ela vai retornar uma nova série (ou dataframe - é difícil dizer, parece que você chamou sua variável de "Series"?? Esse é o nome da classe do Pandas e gera confusão)

De qualquer forma, o que falta é reatribuir o nome para o resultado da chamada a `apply`

```py
Series = Series.apply(zero_to_null)
```

Comment: Entendi. Funcionou. Eu não chame a variável de Series, apenas coloquei um nome genérico para representar o que eu estava fazendo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!